# Creating Transparent Game Menu Items using AndEngine

Tags: android, sprite, andengine, game-engine

I'm trying to create a Game Menu which contains some Menu Items like

1. New Game
2. Multiplayer
3. Options
4. Exit

I want to make this Menu Items Transparent. Only Text in White color should be visible.
So i guess i do not need any background image for Menu Items.

I have seen examples of SpriteButton like given below.

```
ButtonSprite playButton = new ButtonSprite(0, 0, btnNormalTextureRegion, btnPushedTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        // Do Stuff here
     }
}
```

The thing which i don't understand is how can i initialize **btnNormalTextureRegion**?
I use the code give below to initialize ITexture and ITextureRegion for objects.

```
mBackgruondTexture = new BitmapTexture(activity.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return activity.getAssets().open("gfx/backgrounds/greenbg.jpg");                
                }
            });
mBackgruondTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(mBackgruondTexture);
```

This code openes up an Image from assest. 
As i do not want to use any image for Menu Item How can i initialize **btnNormalTextureRegion** for SpriteButton.

OR

Is there any alternative to create Game Menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, an easier alternative would be creating a scene with `Text` objects for each menu item. That's the approach I'm using in one of my game. I uploaded the class to pastebin, see it [here](http://pastebin.com/puepeseS).

Unless you want the menu items to be sprites themselves (That is, pictures and not just plain text) this is a great way to implement a menu.

Comment: Yeahh thats's great !!
THanks for it.
Mean while i came across MenuItem class. which is a quite similar.

Comment: Yea, there's also a `MenuScene` class. I remember investigating this class, but ultimately I chose to create my own menu scene class, I don't remember why though :)